# Hiding vertices doesn't work in sculpt mode

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting, masking

I am trying to do some slight model edits via sculpt mode, but only need some parts to be affected. I find it much easier to select and hide the vertices than to use the mask brush in sculpt mode, but hiding the vertices has no effect because when I exit sculpt mode, some vertices that I hid now appear to have been affected by the sculpting. Is there away for the selected vertices to not be affected without using the mask brush?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thankfully there is a way, though it’s not quite as flexible as edit mode vertex hiding. Has to do with something called “face sets“ if I remember correctly. Look around in the menus for hiding selected faces, and see if you can figure it out. I personally didn’t get very far, but I was able to get something done thankfully.